# Getting an error getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND when trying to send an email using sendGrid and Firebase Trigger email

Tags: email, triggers, sendgrid, firebase-extensions

I created a Firestore collection labeled 'mail' that gets triggered whenever a new document is created, but when I create a new document, the extension returns an error in the document:

[image]

Not sure where the parameter comes from, since the SMTP server provided by sendGrid is something else: smtps://.smtp.gmail.com:465

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid support solved the problem: the SMTP server I had configured to the extension and the SMTP password were both wrong. Once I corrected these errors, I was able to send emails.